# Problems with DBI/odbc packages for R when query involves a linked server

Tags: python, r, sql-server, odbc

The following query retrieves records from our database, when run from python using sqlalchemy (the actual DSN and name of the linked server are hidden here - for illustration I use XYZ and ABC below). The table "NormalizedTradeLatest" is a MSSQL table synonym.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlalchemy as sa

eng = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://XYZ')
ar = pd.read_sql_query(sql="select BusinessId, TradeProviderId, TotalDue from NormalizedTradeLatest", con=eng)
ar.shape
```

> output: (8535866, 3)

However, using R and same query I get:

```
con <- odbc::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = 'XYZ')

ar <- odbc::dbGetQuery(con, "select BusinessId, TradeProviderId, TotalDue from NormalizedTradeLatest")
```

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Could not find server 'ABC' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>  'select BusinessId, TradeProviderId, TotalDue from NormalizedTradeLatest'

Does my odbc::dbConnect statement needs additional parameters?

Comment: which operating system are you using? use server instead of dsn. In windows, dsn should be added in ODBC data sources. Where as in linux add dsn in odbc settings.

Comment: Check the properties of the DSN to ensure that it's actually connecting to the same SQL Server (and Instance Name/Port) as the SQLalchemy code.

Comment: I have a odbc.init with an entry for the DSN. I can query other tables in the database from python or R just fine - only when I try to query a table synonym does R give errors.

Comment: try table name as ````"database"."schema"."tablename"````. the query as  ````"select \"BusinessId\", \"TradeProviderId\", \"TotalDue\" from \"databasename\".\schemaname\".\"NormalizedTradeLatest\""````